Don't understand just this one part of a solution for pell's equation
$x^2-dy^2=1$
$(x-y\sqrt{d})(x+y\sqrt{d})=1$
So $(x_1,y_1)$ is the smallest positive integer value for which this equation holds, which are also the fundamental solutions.
$(x_1-y_1\sqrt{d})(x_1+y_1\sqrt{d})=1$
As we can raise 1 to the power of anything,
$(x_1-y_1\sqrt{d})^n(x_1+y_1\sqrt{d})^n=1$
Which is apparently the same as:
$(x_n-y_n\sqrt{d})(x_n+y_n\sqrt{d})=1$
And here's my problem. How can we just change the subscripts like this? n is supposed to mean the general term, but how can raising the power just change the subscripts? I want to see how it works algebraically.

It is not just changing the subscript. What it says is that if we have a solution $(x_1,y_1)$, then another solution $(x_2,y_2)$ can be obtained by $$x_{\color{red}{2}}+\sqrt{d}y_{\color{red}{2}}=(x_1+\sqrt{d}y_1)^{{\color{red}{2}}}=\underbrace{(x_1^2+dy_1^2)}{x_2}+\sqrt{d}\underbrace{(2x_1y_1)}{y_2}$$

We have Pell's Equation: $x^2 - dy^2 = 1$. After expansion, we saw that:
$$\left(x - y\sqrt d\right)\left(x + y\sqrt d\right) = 1$$
Suppose that you have found the smallest solution by trial-and-error, say $(x_1, y_1)$, then, we can find more sets of solutions through a generative algorithm. From:
$$\left(x_1 - y_1\sqrt d\right)\left(x_1 + y_1\sqrt d\right) = 1$$
squaring both sides yields:
$$\left(x_1^2 + y_1^2d - 2x_1y_1\sqrt d\right)\left(x_1^2 + y_1^2d + 2x_1y_1\sqrt d\right) = 1$$
Thus, it becomes clear that:
$$x_2 = x_1^2 + y_1^2d\ \text{ and }\ y_2 = 2x_1y_1$$
You get the idea, right? Try cubing both sides.
$$\left(x_1^3 + 3x_1y_1^2d - 3x_1^2y_1\sqrt d - y_1^3d\sqrt d\right)\left(x_1^3 + 3x_1y_1^2d + 3x_1^2y_1\sqrt d + y_1^3d\sqrt d\right) = 1$$
Hence, your third set of solutions is:
$$x_3 = x_1^3 + 3x_1y_1^2d\ \text{ and }\ y_3 = 3x_1^2y_1 + y_1^3d$$
In general, what I and that source are trying to convey is that raising both sides by the $n$th power will generate your $n$th set of solutions for Pell's Equation.
Addendum:
If $(x_1, y_1)$ are the first set of solutions to $x^2 - y^2d = 1$, then the $n$th set of solutions by raising both sides by $n$ as explained above is:
$$x_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}x_1^{n-2k}y_1^{2k}d^k$$
$$y_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k+1}x_1^{n-2k-1}y_1^{2k+1}d^k$$
Enjoy number theory!!

$(x_n,y_n)\in\Bbb Z^2$ is defined by
$$x_n+\sqrt dy_n=(x_1+\sqrt dy_1)^n,$$
i.e.
$$x_n=\sum\binom n{2k}x_1^{n-2k}d^ky_1^{2k},\quad y_n=\sum\binom n{2k+1}x_1^{n-2k-1}d^ky_1^{2k+1}.$$
Therefore,
$$(x_1-\sqrt dy_1)^n=x_n-\sqrt dy_n.$$
